# List all possible combinations of variables with factors

Tags: python, numbers, calculation

So I am trying to think of how I can list all possible combinations of 5 variables (that have a set value AND a second property, like a charge for example, so for example I would have x = 100 and has a charge state of +1) with different factors to each variable (so x can vary between 1 and 4, y only between 1 and 2).
At the end I would like to have a list with the combination of variables and the summed value of all like this:
4*x+2*y+3*z = 1400 (3+)

Is this possible? I am trying to wrap my head around this or if there are too many variables in this.
I am a beginner, so explain it like I am dumb.

Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: it kinda goes in the right direction
but how would I go on multiplying the list elements and then returning two values for each combination?